# Filter wordpress search results - not picking up values

Tags: php, wordpress

I am sending my search queries to this directory-search.php template. It gets the results back no problem but as seen, I am trying to filter the results so I can have those with a higher membership_type value at the top instead. Even if I completely remove this filter it still shows the same results in the exact same order, doesn't seem to want to take notice of these arguments.

**The arguments**
directory-search.php template which displays the resut(s) (name, logo etc).

```
<?php 
    $args = array(
        'post_type'=> 'directory_listings',
        's'    => $s,
        'paged' => $paged,
        'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                    'key' => 'membership_type',
                    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
                    'order' => DESC
                    ,
                ),
            ),
        );
?>

<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<div class="listing-image hide-for-small-only">
    <?php 
        $new_logo = get_field('company_logo');
        $old_logo = get_field('old_company_logo');
        if( !empty($new_logo) ):
    ?>

    <img src="<?php echo get_field('company_logo'); ?>" />

    <?php elseif( !empty($old_logo) ): ?>

    <img src="<?php echo get_field('old_company_logo'); ?>" />

    <?php else : ?>

        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="" title="" />

    <?php endif; ?>
</div>


<?php endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not passing your `$args` array anywhere, so wordpress is of course ignoring it. Also, `DESC` should be in a string like `"DESC"`.

This code should work:

```
<?php 
$args = //... your values posted above
$query=new WP_Query($args);
?>

<?php if ($query->have_posts()): ?>
<?php while ($query->have_posts()): $query->the_post(); ?>
<!-- your code here -->
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Take a look at the codex for [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

Comment: Ah I see thanks. Ok I know now that it's taking them into account as if I mess up the post-type for a second I get no results. But the order of results is still in the standard wordpress order, it's not ordering by the meta_value of the key. I tried with meta_key too, same order.